# LINUX 16.04 port blocking and ip blocking

Tags: 16.04, networking, ip, nat

My condition is there is a local network with 3 computers

1. Comp A (10.1.1.7 and 172.16.1.12 and 192.168.0.4)(actually Comp A has 3 network interfaces)
2. Comp B (10.1.1.13)
3. Comp C (172.16.1.5)

Comp A has two network interfaces and I use NAT connect Comp C, which is a Tomcat server, behind Comp A. Also, the NAT is 172.16.1.5:8080<->10.1.1.7:80

Now, I tried to use iptables on Comp A (10.1.1.7):

```bsh
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.1.1.13 -j DROP; sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT;
```

After that, Comp B (10.1.1.13) can't ping Comp A (10.1.1.7) but I still can access the Tomcat page.  I even tried to use the 2nd command (REJECT port 80) to block port 80.

Can I block Comp B (10.1.1.13) so that to Comp B cannot access the Tomcat page.  If I only block the port, can I only not allow access to Tomcat, but still can ping 10.1.1.7? Thanks

My iptables -v -x -n -L:

```bsh
 pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       147.8.179.216        0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       14.0.154.45          0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.1.1.13            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

and, my iptables -v -x -n -L -t -nat:

```bsh
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 35032 packets, 1969104 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     386    19820 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.16.1.5:8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 34737 packets, 1955948 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 312260 packets, 19072061 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 312260 packets, 19072061 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     385    19780 SNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.1.5           tcp dpt:8080 to:172.16.1.12
```

Comment: As a suggestion, instead of iptables, you might consider `ufw` or the graphical `gufw` to do what you're trying to do.  That might be easier.

Comment: You would have to do the filtering in the nat PREROUTING chain. For packets that will end up forwarded to computer C, ipables packet flow would never get to the default INPUT chain so a rule there has no effect. Your `iptables -L` edit doesn't tell us the whole story, we also need to see the nat chains. Suggest: `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the packets you want to drop or reject would otherwise be forwarded to computer C, they don't actually get to the normal INPUT chain. Additionally the nat table is not intended for filtering, so it can not be done there. The mangle PREROUTING table is traversed before the nat PREROUTING table, so filter rules could be placed there.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $EXTIF -p tcp -s 10.1.1.13 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Where $EXTIF is the network interface name.
The above rule was tested on my test computer, using different IP addresses and interface names.

Use [this diagram](http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables/) to help trace iptables packet flow.

Comment: Thanks! I tried and it's work by blocking the port on prerouting.

Comment: @Quincy : Then please accept my answer, as a way to let others know that this question has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your tables, it is hard to say.  You can look at all of your `iptables` by using the `-L` flag, to list them:

```bsh
sudo iptables -L
```

Please update your question with this output, especially if this answer doesn't provide a solution for you.

When reading this output, you must start from the top, and work our way down.  Are there any rules that would REJECT, DROP or ACCEPT your traffic before this line?  Since you're trying to block access, you most likely have an ACCEPT line above the REJECT on port 80.

When using `iptables` command, [you can append rules `-A`, or insert them with `-I`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iptables#Editing_rules).  This means, rules added with `-A` will be at the bottom of the existing rules.  This can make on the fly modifications troublesome, and instead, you load a list of rules from a file:

```bsh
sudo iptables -L # Look at tables, test that they work correctly
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables # Save tables to a file
....
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables # Restore tables after a reboot or something
```

You can also `sudo iptables --flush` to start over with a fresh set of rules that will ACCEPT all connections.